# zend framework when using both mencache and cache page

Tags: zend-framework, memcached, zend-cache

I'm using zend frameword version 1.11

My site using memcache to save session but want using more zend cache page to cache page html

Result: cache page html is **not save right cache dir config**, it save **public** path and **data in file is null** (0 KB)

To be bro help

my config in **application.ini**

```
; MEMCACHE CONFIG
resources.cachemanager.memcached.frontend.name                            = Core
resources.cachemanager.memcached.frontend.options.automatic_serialization = On
resources.cachemanager.memcached.backend.name                             = Memcached
resources.cachemanager.memcached.backend.options.servers.one.host         = 10.60.80.51
resources.cachemanager.memcached.backend.options.servers.one.port         = 11211
resources.cachemanager.memcached.backend.options.servers.one.persistent   = On

; session savehandler class
resources.session.name = PHPGAME1_SESSION
resources.session.saveHandler.class        = Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Cache
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime           = 7200
resources.session.cookie_domain            = ".game5.vn"

;cofig cache page
resources.cacheManager.page.backend.options.public_dir = PUBLIC_PATH "/cached"
resources.cacheManager.pagetag.backend.options.cache_dir = WEB_PATH "/data/cache/tags"
resources.frontController.params.disableOutputBuffering = true
resources.cacheManager.page.backend.options.disable_caching = false
```

**My boostrap to init session handler**

```
protected function _initSessionId()
{
    $opts = $this->getOptions();
    if (isset($opts['resources']['session']['saveHandler']['class']) &&
            'Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Cache' == $opts['resources']['session']['saveHandler']['class']) {
        $this->bootstrap('session');
        $cache = $this->bootstrap('cachemanager')
        ->getResource('cachemanager')
        ->getCache('memcached');
        Zend_Session::getSaveHandler()->setCache($cache);

    }                     
    $defaultNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
    if (!isset($defaultNamespace->initialized)) {
        Zend_Session::regenerateId();
        $defaultNamespace->initialized = true;
    }
}
```

In init controller, i have using helper to save cache page, action which want save cache page

```
$this->_helper->cache(array('index'), array('content'));
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved

I have 2 segment in config: cachemanager and cacheManager, when combining, zend cache only get first segment (cachemanager)

Config success:

```
; CACHE CONFIG
resources.cachemanager.memcached.frontend.name                            = Core
resources.cachemanager.memcached.frontend.options.automatic_serialization = On
resources.cachemanager.memcached.backend.name                             = Memcached
resources.cachemanager.memcached.backend.options.servers.one.host         = 127.0.0.1
resources.cachemanager.memcached.backend.options.servers.one.port         = 11211
resources.cachemanager.memcached.backend.options.servers.one.persistent   = On

; session savehandler class
resources.session.name = PHPGAME5_SESSION
resources.session.saveHandler.class        = Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Cache
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime           = 7200
resources.session.cookie_domain            = ".game5.vn"


; CACHE CONFIG
resources.cachemanager.page.backend.options.public_dir = PUBLIC_PATH "/cached"
resources.cachemanager.pagetag.backend.options.cache_dir = WEB_PATH "/data/cache/tags"
resources.frontController.params.disableOutputBuffering = true
resources.cachemanager.page.backend.options.disable_caching = false
resources.cachemanager.page.backend.options.cache_directory_umask = 0775
resources.cachemanager.page.backend.options.cache_file_umask  = 0775
```